# Using two programs at once, kind of

Tags: python-3.x

This is kind of a misleading subject line...I think.

I have a mapping program where as I scroll across the screen it shows the longitude/latitude where I am and as I scroll across roads or services it brings up on the data on the roads or services and displays them on the left hand side of the screen.  The problem is, even without full data available(by a long shot), this is a completely stand alone program(no internet connection required for any part of the mapping), the program is very data intensive.  This causes the problem that the program is slow to bring up the data any time I zoom in on an area.

I like the fact of having everything on the map, 'active', aka referencible as to what it is.  I don't want to lose that feature of the program.  I use the current tag within Tkinter to let me reference the points as I cross them and that needs to stay available.  Otherwise I could see predrawing the image and saving it and just scrolling across the separate images but I wouldn't still have the current tag capability that I have right now.  I don't want to lose that capability, it's very integral to the program.

I need to find a way to be able to draw zoomed in maps while still 'surfing' on the current map and then be able to display the zoomed in map when I need/want to.

Is there a way of doing that with Python?  I have used subprocess before but it doesn't seem like that would be the right way of doing what I'm trying to do, at least from my recollection of it from when I used it 3-4 years ago.  Maybe I'm wrong though.

I figured I would ask for guidance first since I don't know if the concept is even feasible, and if it is feasible what direction I should do research toward to try to find the answer.

Comment: Look into threads.